# How do I return unique elements of a Union of Collections in Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following problem: I want to return all unique bottles that a critic has reviewed, if any reviewed by them are sold currently in selected shops.
The problem is that I get duplicates in both collections and while I can filter them individually, I cannot filter the joined result:

```
START shop=node:shops('SHOP_ID:...') 
MATCH (shop)-[:SELLS]->(bottle)<-[:REVIEWED]-(critic)-[:REVIEWED]->(other_bottle)  
WITH  critic, COLLECT(DISTINCT(bottle))) + COLLECT(DISTINCT(other_bottle))) as all_bottles 
RETURN wine_critic, all_bottles
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
START shop=node:shops('SHOP_ID:...') 
MATCH (shop)-[:SELLS]->(bottle)<-[:REVIEWED]-(critic)
WITH critic
MATCH (critic)-[:REVIEWED]->(other_bottle)  
RETURN  critic, COLLECT(other_bottle) as all_bottles
```

Comment: One MATCH to get the path, another one to get the data. Cool!

Comment: This is great, thank you! I was trying to get it work through 

START n=node(50), b=node(137) MATCH p=n-[r*1..2]-b RETURN nodes(p); 

to find the mutual neighbors, which it does, but it returns it as a collection, and your example returns the nodes.

Thanks!